# Error sending HTML email template using Marketo

Tags: html, macros, html-table, html-email, marketo

I keep getting an error when sending a sample HTML email. I have no idea what the error means and Marketo support is stumped too. I can't send any emails until this is resolved. I have been building HTML email templates for a while now and this is the first time I have come across this.

Here is the error. An error occurred when processing the email Body!
A macro declaration requires at least a name argument near

```
</table></td><td valign="top" class="spacer" width="20" style
```

Here is the part of code it is referencing.

```
</table>
 </td>
  <td valign="top" name="spacer" class="spacer" width="20" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;padding: 0;line-height: 1px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, but it is hard to say for sure without more information. Please email me at mmanzur@marketo.com with the support case details, and I'll look into this.